# Vaadin select all users

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

How can i get all users registered in Vaadin? I currently know how to get the logged in user

```
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
```

but i want all the users any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how this is related to Vaadin (never used it), but if you want to get every registered user, you can use one of the methods of the User service, such:

```
List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
```

Just be careful to pagination (do you really need **every** user?) that this method will return a `User` bean for every record in the `User_` table, so you will also have deactivated users. Have a look at the `UserLocalServiceUtil.search` method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Actually i need all users of a specific role what can i add to accomplish that?

Comment: Use this as a guideline: you want users, right? So, have a look at the `User` service :-) If you search through the UserLocalServiceImpl class (which is the implementation of the User local service... you definitely have to [learn](http://www.liferay.com/it/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/liferay-s-architecture-the-service-layer) what this means), you'll find the method `getRoleUsers`, which is exactly what you need.